# Electron App: How to 'lock' a computer?

Tags: javascript, atom-editor, electron

I am building an Electron app, which needs to lock the user's PC (for security) after a long task is done.

I am unable to find a way to achieve this.

Is there a way to send Keystrokes (WinKey + L) to the OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows you need to call the [`LockWorkStation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376875%28VS.85%29.aspx) function. You can either write a native Node module to invoke this function, or just execute `rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation` on the command line (which is what the [lockpc](https://github.com/abinpal/lockpc) package does).

Comment: Brilliant! I was unaware of this.